# Passing JSON value to Web Method returns 'Unknown web method DoesUserExist. Parameter name: methodName' error

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json

Hi this is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function validateEmail(email) {
            var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
            if (!emailReg.test(email)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        $("#coreContent_mainContent_txtEmail").blur(function () {
            var email = $("#coreContent_mainContent_txtEmail").val();

            if (!validateEmail(email)) {
                $("#coreContent_mainContent_errorIconEmail").css("display", "block !important").fadeIn(200);
                $("#coreContent_mainContent_txtEmail").css("-webkit-box-shadow", "0 0 0 1px #2D2D2D, 0 0 0 2px #FF0000 !important").fadeIn(200);
                $("#coreContent_mainContent_txtEmail").val('');
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Sign-Up.aspx/DoesUserExist",
                    data: "{'email': '" + email + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        if (msg == "false") {
                            alert("Email Does Not Exist!");  
                        } else {
                            alert("Email Exist!");
                            $(this).css("display", "block !important").fadeIn(200);
                            $(this).css("-webkit-box-shadow", "0 0 0 1px #2D2D2D, 0 0 0 2px #FF0000 !important").fadeIn(200);
                            $(this).val = "";
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Now in the ajax post it give me this error 'Unknown web method DoesUserExist.
Parameter name: methodName' however in my code behind on the same page which is Sign-Up.aspx the method'DoesUserExist' is actually there, this is the code:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static bool DoesUserExist(string email)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

For now for testing purposes i am only returning false in this above method. However the problem still stands that the ajax call is having trouble finding the webmethod. Any Ideas on how i can solve this?

Answer (score 3):

try add [ScriptMethod] DoesUserExist:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static bool DoesUserExist(string email)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i tried it the same error comes up 'Unknown web method initEmailAuthentication.
Parameter name: methodName
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method initEmailAuthentication.
Parameter name: methodName'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your URL is correct in your AJAX post, I'm not sure about your hierarchy but the leading slash might not be required.  A good article to setup a test page here: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To fix it, you should make sure that:

- in your code behind, your method should be static and add at the top of it, the annotation [WebMethod]

`[WebMethod]
public static bool DoesUserExist(string email)
{
    return false;
}`

- in jquery code, make sure the parameters you are passing to data option should match your parameters method name. It has to match your method signature.

  data: "{'email': '" + email + "'}",